# what is the difference between obj.prototype and Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)

Tags: javascript

I create one object using `Object.create` method, so `Object.create` expects **protoptype object** as the first parameter and **property decriptors** are the second parameter.

```
var obj = Object.create({a:2},{b:{value:3}})
```

so, `{a:2}` is the prototype of the obj. but if I am looking for prototype like `obj.prototype` returns `undefined` but if i checks using `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` returning `{a:2}`

Can you tell me whats wrong here?
So, what is the first parameter in `Object.create`?

Thanks

Comment: Syntax: `Object.create(proto[, propertiesObject])`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Plain objects does not have `prototype` propterty. Don't confuse yourself with `functionReference.prototype`

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) == obj.__proto__` But using `__proto__` is not recommended.

Comment: but why Object.create() expecting first parameter as prototype of object

Answer (score 1):

You've found the one thing weirdest about the JavaScript language: the `prototype` property. In JavaScript, objects inherit properties from parent through the prototype chain.

But JavaScript works so that the `prototype` property of an object is not that object's prototype - it is the value that is used as the prototype for further objects created from it using `new`. So `Car.prototype` is the value that's going to be the *prototype* of creating a new instance with `new Car()`.

What actually is the prototype of an object in the prototypal inheritance sense is what you can get with `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. You can learn more about this for example in [Understanding the prototype property in JavaScript](http://bytearcher.com/articles/understanding-prototype-property-in-javascript/)